# Uwp extension binding error. Failed to set "path"

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I have code like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="App4.Views.AddPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App4.Views"
xmlns:conv="using:App4.Converters"
xmlns:extensions="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding AddPageInstance, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <conv:SalaryConverter x:Key="SalaryConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Padding="20" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300">
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Vm.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 x:Name="CharactValidator"
                 Header="Name"
                 PlaceholderText="Type Name here"
                 extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationMode="Dynamic"
                 extensions:TextBoxRegex.ValidationType="Characters"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), ElementName=CharactValidator}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Salary"/>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Vm.Salary, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SalaryConverter}}" PlaceholderText="Type Salary here"/>
        <TextBlock/>
        <TextBlock Text="Title"/>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Vm.Title, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Type Title here"/>
        <TextBlock/>
        <TextBlock Text="Surname"/>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Vm.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Type Surname here"/>
        <TextBlock/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The problem is that i have errors connected with extensions:

Unable to convert "Dynamic" to an object of type "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions.TextBoxRegex+ValidationMode"

Unable to convert "Characters" to an object of type "Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions.TextBoxRegex+ValidationType"

Error Failed to set "Path"

After building the app, it works great. But i don't know how to delete those errors messages and why it appears. If any additional informations are required, please ask me.

Thanks,
Konrad

Answer (score 0):

1. right click solution -> Clean Solution.
2. Repeat step 1
3. close visual studio and reopen it.
4. Rebuild the solution

Comment: Still the same. I added references in code behind but it still shows errors.

Comment: pretty weird bug, have u opened an issue on the community toolkit github repo?

Comment: Not yet. I am trying to check everything step by step to be sure that it is not fault.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue there, it looks like u have everything working in place bcz u r able to succesfully run the build and run the app right?

Comment: Yes I am. And it works as it should. I posted new issue on github repo.
https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2418